# counting number of lines starting with a specific alphabet in UNIX?

Tags: unix

How do I calculate the number of lines starting with "N" in a fastq file in UNIX? I have tried sed but I am not getting an expected output

Comment: Hi, welcome do StackOverflow. Please, show us some code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sh
sed -n '/^N/p' file.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the layout of a fastq file, but can you use `grep`?

```
grep -c "^N" file.txt
```